# malloc(sizeof(s)) allocates less memory than expected?

Tags: c, malloc

hey  i am having problems  using the sizeof operator in malloc. For example see the foll. code-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
char * copy(char *s)
{
    char *t=malloc(sizeof(s));
    char *ptr=s;
    int i=0;
    do
    {
        t[i++]=*ptr++;
    }
    while(*ptr!='\0');
    return t;
}
int main()
{
    char *s="hello adsjahsjkdhjkashdkjaskdasldjlasjdlajsdlkjaslkdjalsjdlasjdljasdljasdkljklsdjlasdsadasdasd";
    char *b=copy(s);
    printf("%s\n",b);
    free(b);
    return 0;
}
```

on ideone, it gives the error:-
*** glibc detected**  ./prog: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x09bcf008 **

But when i replace malloc(sizeof(s)) with malloc(strlen(s)+1) , the program works perfectly. So whats the problem?
NOTE:this is just a small prog i created to demonstrate the problem i was having in another code.

Comment: If `malloc` *ever* allocates less than requested (except for *none* in which case it will return `NULL`) then you've found a bug in the implementation -- congratulations!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The operator `sizeof` doesn't do what you want on pointers. It yields the size of the pointer on your machine (which will be something like 4 or 8).

You can think of it this way: the array decays to a pointer when passed to a function and the information regarding its size is "lost".

---

Also note your loop doesn't fill in the 0 terminator.

Answer (score 6):

You should use [strlen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strlen/) instead of [sizeof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w557fh7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in the `copy` function:

```
char * copy(char *s)
{
    char *t=malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    char *ptr=s;
    int i=0;
    do
    {
        t[i++]=*ptr++;
    }
    while(*ptr!='\0');
    return t;
}
```

The problem is that `sizeof` does not return the value you need, that function will return the size of the `char *s` (probably 4 or 8 -> bytes used to storage that pointer). Check the documentation links to understand more clearly.

One more thing, if you are doing that in order to practice your C skills is OK but if you are not, you will probable just want to use the [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/) function.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Still not enough...`strlen` isn't counting the null terminator.

Comment: 2 @downvoters, please suggest an improvement.... why this question does not have an answer selected yet?

Answer (score 4):

arrays and strings with size information gets degenerated to pointers losing its size attributes when it is passed as a parameter to a function

So when you are calculating the size of the parameter `s` it either returns 32/64 based on your bitness.

instead of `sizeof`, you should actually do `strlen` and add one to it to accommodate the null character.

instead of

```
char *t=malloc(sizeof(s));
```

try

```
char *t=malloc(strlen(s)+1);
```

Please note:

There are other design issues with your code

1. When passing a pointer argument which is not supposed to change, you should declare it const.
2. Generally returning an address of a locally generated heap storage is not a good practice and is the major cause of memory leak, if cal-lee ever forgets to free the storage. Instead pass it as a non-const parameter to the function.

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof(s)` returns the size of `char *s` which is 4 (on 32 bit) or 8 (on 64 bit) systems.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` returns the size of the pointer (usually 4 or 8 bytes), not the size of the pointed-to object.  (There is no way to get at the latter information.  `sizeof` is effectively a compile-time constant, by the way.)

Answer (score 1):

`s` is a pointer to char, so `malloc(sizeof(s))` allocates space for one pointer to char -- typically 2-8 bytes, most often 4 bytes. As it stands, it'll always allocate this fixed amount of space, regardless of the length of string you passed in. In your test, you're passing a much longer string than that, so you overflow the buffer you allocated.

You're already given the correct answer: under the circumstances, `strlen` is the right function to find the size.

Answer (score 0):

malloc is declared in , so we #include that header in any program that calls malloc. A ``byte'' in C is, by definition, an amount of storage suitable for storing one character, so the above invocation of malloc gives us exactly as many chars as we ask for. We could illustrate the resulting pointer like this: